# How to make a drag and drop LineChart using JavaFX?

Tags: java, charts, drag-and-drop, javafx, linechart

I need to create a line graph to allow me to drag it in different coordinate axes, when dragged backward the graph should show data that have already been painted.

"Currently I have some graphs showing real-time data, I receive this data via sockets, then I want to be able to pause the graph and dragging back to see the data that have already been shown."

Comment: Is there a question in there? Are you creating a chart or a graph? Where exactly is the first problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with Javafx, so I apologise if this misses the mark.

I have made something similar in the past using my own component and a JScrollPane. You can make a "scrolling savvy" client, allowing you to render the history as the user drags the graph backwards. If you make your client Scrollable, you have full control on how it responds. While this isn't javafx specific, there is a javafx panel, so I can't see a reason this wouldn't work, assuming comparability with light weight swing components.

Oracle introduce it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable

Comment: Thank you. specifically need an example of JavaFX.